# Pandas resample based on start and end dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have yearly data for electric vehicle charging and that has the total energy "energy (kwh)" for the charge duration. I also have the start charging time and the end charging time in "Y/m/d H:M:S" format. I am trying to create an average energy use column based on the total energy and the start and end times.

I thought I would need the pandas resample function as I have used it to create timed averages before but was not sure how to create a timed averaged between two times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the pandas resample function. You can do it with some of pandas' more basic datetime functionality instead.

First, here's some toy data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(42)

start = pd.date_range("2021-04-21", periods=5, freq="H")
end = start + pd.to_timedelta(np.random.rand(len(start)), unit='h')
energy_total = 100 * np.random.rand(len(start))

df = pd.DataFrame({'start': start, 'end': end, 'energy_total': energy_total})
```

Now we can calculate the charge duration as a Timedelta and convert that to a simple number with `dt.total_seconds()`. We should divide this by 3600 to get the time in hours, since the total energy is given in kWh. Then we can calculate the average energy flow (in kW) by dividing the total energy by this time:

```py
charge_timedelta = df.end - df.start 
charge_hours = charge_timedelta.dt.total_seconds() / 3600

df['energy_flow'] = df.energy_total / charge_hours 
df.round(2)
```

```
    start                end                  energy_total  energy_flow
0   2021-04-21 00:00:00  2021-04-21 00:22:28  15.60          41.65
1   2021-04-21 01:00:00  2021-04-21 01:57:02   5.81           6.11
2   2021-04-21 02:00:00  2021-04-21 02:43:55  86.62         118.33
3   2021-04-21 03:00:00  2021-04-21 03:35:55  60.11         100.41
4   2021-04-21 04:00:00  2021-04-21 04:09:21  70.81         453.84
```